# Why is System.Drawing.Color.Green (0, 128,0)?

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

I thought it should be (0,255,0). Anyone know why?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because the .NET framework uses the [W3C version of the X11 color names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names). There's apparently two different "Green" colors, the X11 one which is (0, 255, 0), and the W3C one which is (0, 128, 0).

It is apparently not known why the W3C (or anybody) adopted this particular list of colors as standard, although I speculate that it's because it's the only real extensive list of "easy-to-use, human-readable" names for some RGB values (I personally can't imagine what the color `#6495ED` looks like until I look it up).

There are differences between the W3C and X11 list (like "Gray" and "Purple" having different RGB values between W3C and X11). Also, the .NET framework defines "DarkSeaGreen" as (143, 188, 139) instead of (143, 188, 143). I wouldn't be surprised if the rationale for these different values was "it looked more Green/Gray/Purple/etc."

Comment: I didn't know about that. Very interesting this was the choice over RGB.

Comment: from the page you refer to green is defined in X11 as (0%, 100%, 0%) but in W3C as (0%, 50%, 0%) which is what the op says the value is the W3C one and not the X11 one

Comment: @Dan D: Right. I made sure to mention that there was two different versions of the color list.

Comment: @Ives: This is still RGB, the only point of contention is what RGB value creates the color associated with each English color word.  One system claims (0,1,0) is green (and this seems to make obvious sense), where the other system uses (0,.5,0) (which I'm guessing produces a green more similar to what a normal person would call "green".

Comment: Nice, I was not aware of that.